# TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
[09:11:17]  build prod started ... 
[09:11:17]  clean started ... 
[09:11:17]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[09:11:17]  copy started ... 
[09:11:17]  ngc started ... 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined
```

When I `ionic cordova build android --prod` this error coming out, but I can `ionic cordova build android or --release` without problem.

google half month already, still cannot give a answer, don't know where got problem

UPDATE:

When I update Ionic-CLI warning coming out

```
[WARN] Detected @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova in your package.json.

       As of CLI 3.8, it is no longer needed. You can uninstall it:

       npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova

[WARN] Detected @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular in your package.json.

       As of CLI 3.8, it is no longer needed. You can uninstall it:

       npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular
```

ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.0.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
    ios-sim    : 6.0.0 
    Node       : v6.11.0
    npm        : 3.10.10 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

**After used option 1**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your are trying to compile ionic 2 project with Ionic 3 CLI.

Two things you can do to resolve this error :

1) Uninstall ionic3 CLI and install ionic2 CLI ( Which i dont prefer as Ionic3 is Latest with lot more functionalities )

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install ionic@2.2.3
```

2) Upgrade your Project to Ionic 3 ( Preferable and easy to do so ) 
Update your package.json :

```
"ionic-angular": "3.6.0"
"typescript": "2.3.4"
```

Update all your Angular dependencies from 2 to 4

```
"@angular/* "= "4.0.0"
```

Then do a `npm install` , your problem may get resolved.

Refer this [Article](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-an-ionic-2-project-to-ionic-3) for seamless migration

Comment: ok..I will try it now, but which one you perfer? Nomally I use ionic2, if I update to ionic3 is it got different?

Comment: If you are comfortable with ionic2, then go with option 1 ie. uninstall and install ionic2.2.3 which is very much stable.

Comment: After I used option 1, 'ionic serve -l' cannot use, said : '-bash: /usr/local/bin/ionic: No such file or directory'

Comment: option 2 just change that two things, then finish update to ionic3?

Comment: Option 1 : after ionic uninstall do : npm cache clean -f    and then install ionic 2 ie. npm install ionic@2.2.3.

Option 2 : Its actually 3 things, u need to change angular from 2 to 4. Check out the Article Post inline of the Answer for help.

Comment: I used option 1 still not working for me, I will update to question, check please, thank you

Comment: Your npm is broken. Try to Uninstall NODE. and install it by downloading from https://nodejs.org/en/

Then Install cordova and ionic 
ie. 
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g ionic@2.2.3

Comment: After I set up all, 'cordova is not a valid task' this error coming out when I ionic cordova build android --prod

Answer (score 0):

Update your Ionic-CLI

```
npm install ionic@latest
```

Comment: Can i know your Development environment ie.
Ionic Version, Cordova version, Whether your project is Ionic 2 or ionic 3 ?

Comment: I will update into my question and one more thing is when I update ionic-CLI some warning coming out, I also will update the warning to my question

Comment: Check my new answer. @YuyangHe